# Spring Transaction Rollback withour exception

Tags: spring, spring-transactions

Is there a way to to supress or catch the org.springframework.transaction.UnexpectedRollbackException exception when a rollback happens in Spring Transaction.

I have a situation where i do not want to show a 500 page to the user when the rollback happens.

Comment: `try { someBean.doSomethingTransactional(); } catch (UnexpectedRollbackException e) { ... }`?

Comment: that won't work, i tried it already.

Comment: Yes, it will. Why wouldn't it It's plain Java exception catching? Of course, doSomethingTransactional must be the method that actually starts the transaction. If you already in the transaction, that indeed won't work.

Comment: I am taking about Spring declarative transaction. My bad I should have mentioned in the question I asked. Transactions are managed by proxies. so won't be able to catch the exception in the annotated method.

Comment: That's my point. The method **calling** the transactional method should catch the exception. Not the method annotated with Transactional.

Comment: I would recommend you to have a global exception handler using @ControllerAdvice annotation to send appropriate message to the client in the case of exception. Reference https://spring.io/blog/2013/11/01/exception-handling-in-spring-mvc